# How to disable checkbox for a row in rowselection in react-data-grid

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-grid-layout, react-graph-vis

```
 <ReactDataGrid
    columns={[
        { key: 'time', name: 'time', width: 140, formatter: (props) => (<span>{props.value}</span>), sortable: true },
        { key: 'Size', name: 'Size', width: 80, formatter: (props) => (<span>{props.value}</span>) },
        { key: 'qaw', name: 'dash Value', width: 350 },
    ]}
    rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
    rowsCount={list.length}
    emptyRowsView={() => (<div />)}
    rowSelection={{
        showCheckbox: true,
        onRowsSelected: this.onVersionRowsSelect,
        onRowsDeselected: this.onVersionRowsDeselect,
        selectBy: {
            indexes: this.state.selectedIndexes
        }
    }}
/>
```

Above is my code of react-data-grid.
I want to disable row selection for particular row on some condition or want to disable checkbox for that specific row.

Please let me know how it can be achieved.
Thanks

Comment: @parashm were you able to find a proper method to achieve this ? I have a requirement where I want all the checkboxes disabled according to a condition.

Comment: @Dante_97 still didn't find the proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the selection of the row by doing the following:-

```
onVersionRowsSelect(rows) {
    rows = rows.filter(item => !item.row.isSnapshotQuarantined)
    this.setState({
        selectedIndexes: this.state.selectedIndexes.concat(rows.map(r => r.rowIdx))
    });
}
```

I am not sure if you can change the visual effect of disabling the checkbox as the checkbox html's control is not exposed by `react-data-grid` (as per my knowledge).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, bro... This is a workaround.
And not a proper solution.